# Ruby/Heroku app errors "We're sorry, but something went wrong" troubleshooting

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying to setup an Elo rating system for my local 8 ball pool league using:
https://github.com/elovation/elovation

The only changes I have made to above repo prior to deployment are specifying `heroku:stack-18` in app.json and running `bundle install` after specifying to use https:// instead of git://

I have deployed my app to Heroku without error but when loading my app I get a "We're sorry, something went wrong page"

After deployment I have ran `heroku run rake db:migrate` and `heroku restart` but my error persists

I have included below output of `heroku logs` ; any help with the below errors would be greatly appreciated as I am not particularly familiar with Ruby or Heroku postgres.

```
2022-06-21T12:54:08.886300+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-21T12:54:08.886206 #9]  INFO -- : [dc5be6b7-715a-47a0-8936-e0ba1c6b2c13] Processing by DashboardController#show as HTML
2022-06-21T12:54:08.888800+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2022-06-21T12:54:08.888726 #9] DEBUG -- : [dc5be6b7-715a-47a0-8936-e0ba1c6b2c13]   Player Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "players".* FROM "players"
2022-06-21T12:54:08.889854+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-21T12:54:08.889789 #9]  INFO -- : [dc5be6b7-715a-47a0-8936-e0ba1c6b2c13]   Rendering dashboard/show.html.erb within layouts/application
2022-06-21T12:54:08.891005+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2022-06-21T12:54:08.890942 #9] DEBUG -- : [dc5be6b7-715a-47a0-8936-e0ba1c6b2c13]   Game Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "games".* FROM "games" ORDER BY updated_at DESC
2022-06-21T12:54:08.891468+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-21T12:54:08.891374 #9]  INFO -- : [dc5be6b7-715a-47a0-8936-e0ba1c6b2c13]   Rendered dashboard/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.5ms)
2022-06-21T12:54:08.893279+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2022-06-21T12:54:08.893225 #9]  INFO -- : [dc5be6b7-715a-47a0-8936-e0ba1c6b2c13] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)
2022-06-21T12:54:08.894220+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2022-06-21T12:54:08.894169 #9] FATAL -- : [dc5be6b7-715a-47a0-8936-e0ba1c6b2c13]
2022-06-21T12:54:08.894271+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2022-06-21T12:54:08.894239 #9] FATAL -- : [dc5be6b7-715a-47a0-8936-e0ba1c6b2c13] ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "chartkick.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.
2022-06-21T12:54:08.894272+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2022-06-21T12:54:08.894439+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2022-06-21T12:54:08.894403 #9] FATAL -- : [dc5be6b7-715a-47a0-8936-e0ba1c6b2c13]     11:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
2022-06-21T12:54:08.894440+00:00 app[web.1]: [dc5be6b7-715a-47a0-8936-e0ba1c6b2c13]     12:   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
2022-06-21T12:54:08.894441+00:00 app[web.1]: [dc5be6b7-715a-47a0-8936-e0ba1c6b2c13]     13:
2022-06-21T12:54:08.894441+00:00 app[web.1]: [dc5be6b7-715a-47a0-8936-e0ba1c6b2c13]     14:   <%= javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick" %>
2022-06-21T12:54:08.894442+00:00 app[web.1]: [dc5be6b7-715a-47a0-8936-e0ba1c6b2c13]     15: </head>
2022-06-21T12:54:08.894442+00:00 app[web.1]: [dc5be6b7-715a-47a0-8936-e0ba1c6b2c13]     16: <body>
2022-06-21T12:54:08.894443+00:00 app[web.1]: [dc5be6b7-715a-47a0-8936-e0ba1c6b2c13]     17:   <div id='container'>
2022-06-21T12:54:08.894482+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2022-06-21T12:54:08.894452 #9] FATAL -- : [dc5be6b7-715a-47a0-8936-e0ba1c6b2c13]
2022-06-21T12:54:08.894523+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2022-06-21T12:54:08.894495 #9] FATAL -- : [dc5be6b7-715a-47a0-8936-e0ba1c6b2c13] app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:14:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___4496802780226790006_47054455194320'
```